# Chrome's HTML5 audio controls have a transparent background. How to fix this?

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, media-player

I have an `<audio>` element in a webpage. I'm happy to use the native browser controls, which are fine in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome for the Mac.

However, Chrome (12.0.742.122 on Windows 7) is displaying the native audio player without any background:

[image: Chrome PC]

For comparison's sake, here's how it looks on Chrome (14.0.835.0) on OSX:
[image: Chrome OSX]

I realise my Mac's a couple of versions forward (it's on the dev channel) but this seems like a surprising issue. Any idea how to fix it?

Alternatively, can anyone recommend a completely painless player (with flash fallback) that I can drop it to style them all the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrapped it in a div with a medium-gray background, wouldn't it work around the problem in Chrome 12 and still look the same in Chrome 14?

Comment: Actually, to clarify, I just applied a background to the actual `audio` element. It now looks wonky in IE9 (the audio element appears to be bigger than the actual player), but that seems fixable through judicious tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82170

Comment: Spot on! Thanks for the heads up.